# SQL Query - Count and Sum - Sport statistics

Tags: mysql

I am running a small project where I try to calculate number of events from a log. Each line in the log (transferred into a table) consists with data as per below table.

I have a table as per below.

```
|NN | XX | YY | ZZ |
+---+----+----+----+
| A |  A |  B |    |
| B |  B |  A |  C |
| A |  A |  C |  B |
| C |  C |  B |  A |
| C |  C |  A |    |
```

Would like to transfer into below table.

```
|NN | XX | YY | ZZ | 
+---+----+----+----+
| A |  2 |  2 |  1 |
| B |  1 |  2 |  1 |
| C |  2 |  1 |  1 |
```

Meaning: For each unique value in column NN count number of NN value in column XX, YY and ZZ

How can this be done by writing an query?

Comment: What have you tried so far? As a hint I'd try PIVOT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly ugly query, but then again your data does not appear to be normalized.  We can join a series of subqueries which find the letter counts for each of the columns:

```
SELECT
    t.NN,
    xx.cnt_xx AS XX,
    yy.cnt_yy AS YY,
    zz.cnt_zz AS ZZ
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT NN FROM yourTable ) t
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT XX, COUNT(*) AS cnt_xx FROM yourTable GROUP BY XX ) xx
    ON t.NN = xx.XX
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT YY, COUNT(*) AS cnt_yy FROM yourTable GROUP BY YY ) yy
    ON t.NN = yy.YY
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ZZ, COUNT(*) AS cnt_zz FROM yourTable GROUP BY ZZ ) zz
    ON t.NN = zz.ZZ
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

In mysql it is little difficult. You can use:

```
select t.NN, 
(select count(XX) from `table` where XX = t.NN) as `XX`,
(select count(YY) from `table` where YY = t.NN) as `YY`,
(select count(ZZ) from `table` where ZZ = t.NN) as `ZZ`
from (select distinct NN from `table`) as t;
```